# Region Display based on value selected in a Radio Group

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a requirement that 2 different regions need to displayed based on the value chosen by the user through a radio button.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Hi Abhinav Dhiman, did you still need help with this or did Littlefoot’s answer work? If it worked, please accept the answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use Server side condition for each of those regions. Suppose radio group values are `1` and `2`, then you might use a function that returns Boolean:

```
return :P1_RADIO_GROUP = 1;
```

so - if condition is met, region will be displayed.